# authentication and access control in IoT

Tags: access-control

I am researching in authentication and access control in IoT. Is there any difference between working in wireless sensor nodes and IoT in the topic authentication and access control as both require lightweight designs?

Comment: Have a look at the analyst community in particular Kuppingercole and their conferences. They have a lot of work on that. Also, Identiverse in Boston next week addresses Identity & Access Mgmt including for IoT

Answer (score 3):

Not much, my impression is that the problems are more or less the same. People change the term to IoT because it sounds sexier than wireless sensors (and they can sell the same thing again as new). Another similar term is pervasive (ubiquitous) computing. Yet another related term is edge computing or fog computing.

The main underlying research challenges for security in all those are often the following:

1. resource-limited devices
2. lack of trust
3. decentralized
4. weak physical security
5. hard to update
6. often has energy constraints

just to name a few.

Comment: What are the solutions?  2 just means “trust no one” which is good practice anyway.  5 can be solved by an automatic updator that verifies signatures on downloads (this assumes your device can do TFTP). 4 again means “trust no one”.  1 just means you get what you pay for.